# Can I replace a fused UK plug with a regular plug?

Tags: fuses

I hope this question is appropriate. 
I bought a dremel rotary tool from Amazon and got a UK plug with a fuse. 
Now I want to replace the plug to one that will fit the outlet in my country. 
We don't have fuses on our plugs, of course. 
Should there be a problem, or will it be a problem only in the UK?

Comment: Omitting a fuse doesn't alter the behavior under normal conditions. Do you have a plan for not-so-normal conditions like fuses in your distribution box?

Answer (score 1):

I would use good quality receptacle adapter. If you start modifying device you (most probably) will not be able to return it if it will appear defective.

And I hope that your country and tool's input voltage and AC rating [match](http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plug-voltage-by-country/).

Comment: I'm waiting for one that I had ordered. In the meanwhile, i have improvised an adapter from a US TO EU adapter and it works fine. The voltage matches, it's OK! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The fuse in UK plugs is there to protect the cable from melting in the event of a short circuit or some other scary<sup>TM</sup> event. Protecting the user or the device is only of secondary consideration if at all.

If your country doesn't use fused plugs, and the voltage/frequency the dremel is rated for matches your country, then you can replace with whatever is the standard plug you require.

I am not sure that the tool has mixed voltage support. If this is the case and you bought it in the UK which uses 230V (nominal), you probably couldn't for example use it in a country like the US which uses 110V (nominal). Whereas you could use it anywhere in Europe where 230V is also the standard.

Comment: The voltage is not a problem, only the plug. I use 220V. Thank you for your answer. I have found a way to power it up with a hacked US TO EU  adapter. Thank you! It